# Locally compact fields are spherically complete

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Was just reading Schneider's Non-archimedian Functionalanalysis and on page 7 he states that in every locally compact field K the intersection of Balls $\underset{n \in \mathbb N}{\bigcap} B_n $ is nonempty for every decreasing sequence  $B_1 \supseteq B_2 \supseteq B_3 \supseteq ...$ of Balls in  K, hence that K is spherically complete. So i want to show that being locally compact implies being spherically complete. I tried using the definitions but could not get very far. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: The book i am reffering to can be found here: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd94_33_TUAhWCbVAKHShZAWwQFghAMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwwwmath.uni-muenster.de%2Fu%2Fpschnei%2Fpubl%2Flectnotes%2Fnfa.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEACB3g5--PQ2WgFRAFRe273UpeRQ

Comment: Take the one-point compactification, $\hat{K}$ of $K$, and show that if $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}B_n$ is empty then $\{\hat{K} - B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open covering of $\hat{K}$. Now reach a contradiction.

Comment: @JoãoCaminada Why is $\hat{K}-B_n$ open in $\hat{K}$? I know that $K$ is open in $\hat{K}$, but to my knowledge, it isn't closed...so the closedness of $B_n$ in $K$ doesn't imply that the ball is closed in $\hat{K}$. In fact, I think that this is only the case if $B_n$ is already compact, since the open sets in $\hat{K}$ are given precisely by the open sets in $K$ and the sets $\hat{K}-L$, where $L$ is compact (in $K$). I'm don't know much about this particular topic, though, so correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @haemi You are right, but in a locally compact, nonarchimedean field with non-trivial absolute value, all balls are compact.

Comment: @JoãoCaminada Oh alright...I got confused by your use of $\hat{K}$ - if all balls are compact, you could apply the argument to $B_1 - B_n$, $n\geq 2$, which is an open cover of $B_1$ if $\bigcap_{n}B_n$ is empty.

Comment: Yeah, that's simpler!